# Добавить данные highcharts addseries R

Tags: r, highcharts

Мне нужно добавить данные, которые собраны в файлах dataframe название myData (1 столбец - дата, 2 - значения).

myData

```
         Date   Value

1  2017-12-01      95
2  2017-12-06      97
3  2017-12-11      96
```

myData2. Даты одинаковые у myData и myData2, значения разные и их несколько соответствуют 1 дате.

```
         Date     Value

1  2017-12-01      95.2
2  2017-12-01      96.1
3  2017-12-06      97.1
4  2017-12-06      96.5
5  2017-12-11      97.8
6  2017-12-11      96.4
```

Нужно, чтобы по оси Х выводилась дата, а по оси Y - значение.
Я пытался сделать:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Статистическое управление процессом")
    sidebarLayout(
     mainPanel(
       highchartOutput("hcontainer1", height = "800px")
              )
                 )
               )  

server = function(input, output) {
# Настройка параметров графика

output$hcontainer1 <- renderHighchart({
  hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series( name = 'Value',
                 data = list(list(myData$Date, myData$Value)),  
                 type = input$plot_type ) %>%
  hc})

}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий код аналогичного графика выглядит следующим образом:

```
library(highcharter)

DF1 <- data.frame(
    Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01"), length.out = 15),
    Value = sample(1:100, size = 15, replace = TRUE)
)

DF2 <- data.frame(
    Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01"), length.out = 15),
    Value = sample(1:100, size = 15, replace = TRUE)
)

highchart() %>% 
    hc_add_series(data = DF1, type = "line", hcaes(x = Date, y = Value)) %>% 
    hc_add_series(data = DF2, type = "line", hcaes(x = Date, y = Value)) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", labels = list(format = "{value:%Y-%m-%d}")) %>% 
    hc_tooltip(xDateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое. Только возник еще 1 вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы выводились на оси Х только те значения, которые указаны в Date?

Прикрепил скриншот, как выводится к вопросу

Также, при наведении на точку, пишется дата в секундах, как это изменить?

Comment: Лучше оформите отдельным вопросом с кодом, который поможет воспроизвести ваш график.

Comment: `hc_tooltip(xDateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: Понял, вынесу в отдельный вопрос.

По данным, появилась ещё 1 проблема, если добавляю такую же таблицу с данными на график (добавил в вопросе myData2), то график не отображается некорректно отображается

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Приведите пример кода, включая отрывок реальных данных, который позволит воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример данных myData2

Comment: Ваши данные некорректны: несколько значений по оси Y соответствуют одному значению по оси X. Агрегируйте данные перед построением графика или добавьте столбец, маркирующий из какой таблицы эти данные, который нужно будет указать в `hcaes` (`group`).

Comment: То есть если несколько значений по Y соответствуют 1 значению по X - данные нельзя вывести?

Comment: Можно, но не данным типом графика. Точками скорее всего можно.

Comment: Почему-то не получается добавить, прикрепил к вопросу строку кода, как добавляю. Просто не строи график вообще

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: В итоге, я хочу, чтобы было 2 Series. 
Первый - линия по значениям Value таблицы myData.
Второй - точки со значениями Value2 из таблицы myData2
Рисунок добавил в вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь два набора данных.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо